# Trying to merge a Linux network Function into a Winsock program

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

I am trying to implement parts of a Linux based network Tic-Tac-Toe program into a Winsock server program. I am having some issues as the Linux version opens a socket as in integer variable:
`int client_sock = 0;` however, in the Winsock application a Csocket object is created: `m_pClientSocket = new CSocket();`

Now obviously when I try to compile the function that sends the players move to the server:

```
if (!SendStatus(client_sock, MOVE)) { 
ServerDisconnected(); 
}
```

I get an invalid variable type error as the function is expecting an int and it's receiving a Csock object.

My question is how do I get the functions to work? I have tried getting the socket handle and using that but I'm not sure if that's the right direction and using **this** `SendStatus(this->m_pClientSocket->GetSocketHandle(), WIN);` is giving me issues as it's a static function.

**Send Status Function:**

```
bool SendStatus(int socket, StatusCode status)
{
    char* data = (char*)&status;
    size_t left = sizeof(status);
    ptrdiff_t rc;

    while (left)
    {
        rc = send(socket, data + sizeof(status) - left, left, 0);
        if (rc <= 0) return false;
        left -= rc;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**TakeTurn Function:**

```
bool TakeTurn(TTTBoard& board)
{
    bool game_over = false;
    bool input_good = false;
    int row = 0, col = 0;

    // Display the board
    board.DrawBoard();

    while (!input_good)
    {
        printf("Enter move (row col): ");

        // Make sure two integers were inputted
        if (scanf_s("%d %d", &row, &col) == 2)
        {
            if (row < 0 || row > 2)
                printf("Invalid row input. Try again.\n");
            else if (col < 0 || col > 2)
                printf("Invalid column input. Try again.\n");
            else if (!board.IsBlank(row, col))
                printf("That cell isn't blank. Try again.\n");
            else
                input_good = true;
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid move input. Try again.\n");

        // flush any data from the internal buffers
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }

    board.PlayerMakeMove(row, col);
    cout << "Sending move to server" << endl;

    // Send the move to the server
    if (!SendStatus(client_sock, MOVE))
        ServerDisconnected();

    if (!SendInt(client_sock, row))
        ServerDisconnected();

    if (!SendInt(client_sock, col))
        ServerDisconnected();

    // Check for win/draw
    if (board.IsWon())
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!!!!" << endl;
        game_over = true;
        SendStatus(client_sock, WIN);
    }
    else if (board.IsDraw())
    {
        cout << "You tied ._." << endl;
        game_over = true;
        SendStatus(client_sock, DRAW);
    }

    return game_over;
}
```

Hopefully I have shared enough info, I didn't want to bloat the question, thanks!

Comment: You're using sockets at the lowest level in your non-Windows code, why not continue to do that when porting to Windows? Why do you start using the `CSocket` abstraction? If you want to use higher-level classes and abstractions, I recommend you find some platform-independent socket library to handle that part of the code for you, as then it should hopefully just be a matter of a recompile on Windows.

Comment: So this won't be as easy as changing a few lines, maybe adding a couple of functions? Haha Both bases of these programs were not originally written by me however I've added to them. I'm trying to learn how they work before fully writing my own. If yo can explain to me the different level of sockets or point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.